# Product.app file red in xcode product folder

Tags: ios, xcode, build-settings

My product.app is red. When I try and run the app on an actual device with the scheme build configuration set to release I get the error "The application does not have a valid signature." It only runs without the error when the scheme build setting is set to debug, which of course does nothing to remedy the red product.app. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Google "code signing".